# Running a server OS from an USB stick in 2017

Tags: linux, usb-flash-drive, server-setup

I want to install Fedora as server OS on a USB3 flash drive.

I wonder if now in 2017 they would be reliable, durable, and fast enough for that purpose?

I plan to have an additional large HDD for storage, but I would like to decouple the OS into another drive.

A fast 32 GB USB3-drive should be more than enough for that.

I actually found some SSD-drives in the housing of an USB-stick, but they cost around 100€ which I find expensive.

Comment: You _can_ run a server from USB, the real question is _should_ you. Why do you need to set up the OS this way? In just about any situation I can think of, it will be much worse than using a traditional drive.